# Accessing ADAM instance without original creator's account

Tags: adam

I have an ADAM instance that was created by a previous employee.  He has since been terminated and his AD account deleted.  I want to be able to access this ADAM instance he created but am not a user in/on it.  Is there a way to take over the schema/instance without knowing the original admin's account info so that I can have full access to it?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but yes this is possible if you have admin rights over the server itself where adam is running. so even if you haven't been granted admin rights over the instance you can make yourself an admin. I am still hesitant to give details as it can be used "maliciously". If you search using your favorite search engine you will find the details.